# WHMCS htaccess to allow downloading

Tags: .htaccess, whmcs

With WHMCS you can't download files if using HTTPS. E.g. The following line DOES NOT WORK:

```
https://www.mysite.com/client/dl.php?type=a&id=239&i=0
```

However, this works:

```
http://www.mysite.com/client/dl.php?type=a&id=239&i=0
```

So, my question is, how do I add a redirect rule to the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !svn.namhost.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  \.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www   [OR]
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} !\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}     !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.mysite.com/$0 [R=301,L]
```

So that if you access:

```
https://www.mysite.com/client/dl.php?type=a&id=239&i=0
```

It opens:

```
http://www.mysite.com/client/dl.php?type=a&id=239&i=0
```

???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/client/dl.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Should work. Doesn't seem like the stuff you already have should interfere because it excludes stuff with www, but if it does, you can just add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/client/dl.php
```

to your first block (before the `RewriteRule`).